# Working with dynamic types on Google Cloud Datastore

Tags: c#, dynamic, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

Our application is currently working on MongoDb. Our plan is to make it work with Datastore. In our application, there are some API calls and we don't know how its response is structured. So, we work with dynamic types. We get response and put it to Mongodb as is.

As far as we examined, Google.Cloud.Datastore.V1 .Net SDK pushes developers to work with structured type. We have to create an entity which has certain properties with predefined key names.

As shown below:

```
        MapField<string, Value> fields = new MapField<string, Value>();
        fields.Add("d1", "string value");
        fields.Add("d2", 30);
        fields.Add("d3", 55);

        var entity = new Entity
        {
            Key = key,
            Properties = { fields }
        };
```

What I've already tried is to set API response to a field. Unfortunately it ended up saving response as a string.

Is there anyway to achive it?

Comment: I understand that you are creating an Entity in Datastore, from an API call to a C# application, that is created with dynamic fields depending on the input request parameters. 
Can you share an example API request that you might receive in this application, and what you expect to be created in Datastore versus what you are getting?

Comment: Let me clear it.

https://gist.github.com/onuar/728e498db627ecae1d0d10e9639643ce
As you can see above, I have a dynamic object called mockedApiResponse that I don't know what is in there. Given example there are just three key but there would be more.

In that way, SDK saved as below:
https://imgur.com/fUasyHL
And I'm not able to filter by number, str or array.

To make it work, I have to do something like that:
https://gist.github.com/onuar/95ca8fabf929d822849cdd8310313731

https://imgur.com/atuCN4C
It worked well. But the problem is, I have to know dJson's properties (keys).

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is simplified if you take int account that you don't need to use the `Properties`  entity key.

I did the following, basing this in your examples. Note that i'm not a `C#` expert as you will see, but this did the trick:

```
string projectId = "MY-PROJECT";
string kind = "Task";
string name = "samplekey1";

DatastoreDb db = DatastoreDb.Create(projectId);

KeyFactory keyFactory = db.CreateKeyFactory(kind);

Key key = keyFactory.CreateKey(name);

var request = JObject.Parse("{number:1000, str:'string', array: [1,2,3,4,5,6]}");

var entity = new Entity()
{
    Key = key,
};

foreach(JProperty property in request.Properties())
{
    entity[property.Name] = property.Value.ToString();
}


using (DatastoreTransaction transaction = db.BeginTransaction())
{
    transaction.Insert(entity);
    transaction.Commit();
};
```

Note that this will not save the type of the values for each key (all of them will be Strings). This is not an issue if you don't need the Type (i.e. Int, String...) for each value to be used later.

However this seems to be the easiest solution, and it gets the job done to create [each property with each value](https://storage.googleapis.com/public-bucket-joan/datastore.png).

Comment: Thanks for your help but it would not be working. Because of data types and nested object. Isn't weird for a NoSQL database that not having json or dynamic type as an argument?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this page in the documentation [Properties and Value Types](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#properties_and_value_types), specially the bit named **Embedded entity** which will allow you to store a JSON entity, and then query its subproperties as long as it is indexed.

Comment: Thank you Amanda. But in .Net SDK, there is nothing such as EmbeddedEntity. I am able to pass an entity through an entity (inner entity). But it's just an another entity. Thus it won't be indexed.

Comment: @onuradam did you resolved this issue, if yes please share the solution, I am also facing the same issue.